# Detect column change by row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

First of all, I have really searched for similar code but I did not find anything suitable.

What I want to do is to show the rows when the employee_type_id changes for each employee, listing the **employee_id**, the **date from** and **last** **date_to** for the coresponding **Employee ID**.

I tried with partition by and lag function but I did not manage to solve this.

Any help is appreciated.

I have this:

```
employee_id   Date_From               Date_To                 EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------
11223344      2016-11-07 00:00:00.000 2016-12-11 00:00:00.000 1
11223344      2016-12-12 00:00:00.000 2016-12-31 00:00:00.000 1
11223344      2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 2017-04-28 00:00:00.000 38
11223344      2017-04-29 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000 38
11223344      2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 2017-11-30 00:00:00.000 1
11223344      2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2018-01-04 00:00:00.000 38
...
22233344      2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 2012-10-31 00:00:00.000 1
22233344      2012-11-01 00:00:00.000 2014-02-28 00:00:00.000 1
22233344      2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2018-01-04 00:00:00.000 39
22233344      2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 2018-03-09 00:00:00.000 2
```

and this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
employee_id   Date_From              EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID
----------- -----------------------  ----------------
11223344      2016-11-07 00:00:00.000 2016-12-31 00:00:00.000 1
11223344      2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000 38
11223344      2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 2017-11-30 00:00:00.000 1
11223344      2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2018-01-04 00:00:00.000 38
...
22233344      2012-06-01 00:00:00.000 2014-02-28 00:00:00.000 1
22233344      2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 2018-01-04 00:00:00.000 39
22233344      2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 2018-03-09 00:00:00.000 2
```

Comment: As a hint for you, this is a gaps and island problem.

Comment: Are there gaps in the dates?  Are there overlaps?  What should be done in those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Time Biegeleisen, this is typical gaps and islands problem. You want to group together "adjacent" rows that have the same `employee_id` and `employee_type_id`.

Here is one way to solve it using window functions:

```
select
    employee_id,
    min(date_from) date_from,
    max(date_to) date_to,
    employee_type_id
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by employee_id order by date_from) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by employee_id, employee_type_id order by date_from) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by employee_id, employee_type_id, rn1 - rn2
```

The inner query ranks records over two different partitions (per employee, and per employee *and* type). When the difference between the row numbers changes, a new island starts (you can run the subquery independently and see the result it produces). Then, the outer query just aggregates by group.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no gaps, you can do this with `lag()`/`lead()` and window functions as well:

```
select employee_id, EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID,
       date_from,
       coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, lead(date_from) over (partition by emplyee_id order by date_from),
                max_date_to
               ) as date_to
from (select t.*,
             lag(EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID) over (partition by employee_id order by date_from) as prev_et,
             max(date_to) over (partition by employee_id) as max_date_to
      from t
     ) t
where prev_et is null or prev_et <> EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID;
```

The possible advantage of this approach is that it does not require aggregation.  That could be a performance gain.